# Push button restarts the arduino

Tags: button

I have linked an external push red colored button to my arduino but when I press it, instead of giving me HIGH or LOW, it resets the arduino. I am a beginner to this stuff so could someone help?

Comment: It is odd that you omitted your code and a schematic or image or even description of your wiring but made *sure* to let us know that the button is **red** =)

Comment: Yes. Change it to a green button and all will be well :P

Comment: Why don’t you show (or at least describe) how you’ve connected the button so we don’t have to guess? There are very many ways to connect an external red button to an Arduino.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

If your button creates a short circuit between 5V and GND pins... it will certainly act like a RESET.  Let's try to make sure you are not creating a dead short on an Arduino pin so you avoid prematurely killing your controller.

Comment: Thank you. Changing it to 3.3 V also does the trick

Comment: @SiddharthAgrawal please fix the real issue. Creating a short on 3.3V maybe doesn't reset the Arduino, but in general, shorts are to be avoided. Unless you like fire, sparks,  and/or broken electronics.

Comment: Ok I'll add the resistance. Thanks